# Custom Button Javascript....Webservice is not called

Tags: javascript, ajax, ajax-toolkit

Return value from Apex method to Javascript in Salesforce using a custom button.For that i have controller :

```
global class web
{
    Webservice static String fetch(Id localId)
    {
        return localId;
    }
}
```

And Custom Button Javascript:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js")}

var r = confirm("Are you sure want to fetch?");

if(r == true)
{
    var a = sforce.apex.execute("web","fetch",{ID:"{!Account.Id}"});
    alert(a);
}
else
{
    alert('Operation aborted');
}
```

When i clicked on custom Button one alert box appeared "Are you sure want to fetch?" that's ok after that second alert box give me the Error.Error is

A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered:

```
{faultcode:'soapenv:Client', faultstring:'No operation available for request {http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/package/web}fetch, please check the WSDL for the service.', }
```

So what can i do to solved the above problem...Please help me....

Snapshot of the Problem....

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a namespace for your org you are working in? Say, if the namespace of the org is "abc", try the following code:

`var a = sforce.apex.execute('abc.web', 'fetch', {localId:'{!Account.Id}'});`

Comment: Thnaks Sir....this is very helpful...thanks again....

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to change the parameter name to **localId**.

Change this:

```
var a = sforce.apex.execute("web","fetch",{ID:"{!Account.Id}"});
```

by this:

```
var a = sforce.apex.execute("web","fetch",{localId:"{!Account.Id}"});
```

Comment: thanks for replay Sir,I just tried as a localId but the problem was not solved...please give me other solutions...

Comment: try by changing the parameter type to string. This also, could generate a problem: `fetch(Id localId)` should be `fetch(String localId)`

Comment: I tried Sir but not solved but here  i think, the problem in WSDL for the service..I works on developer account so is it not a problem?

Comment: Your class definition and javascript call are ok. The WSDL is not the problem, because you don't have to create it when you are referring sforce lib.   

I've created your same sample applied the mentioned fixes and it worked fine.

Comment: Sir Here i add the snapshot of the alert box of the above defined problem...sir please help me to solve the problem...

Comment: Sir please check this link i was applied same step but i was faced an Error       http://www.infallibletechie.com/2013/02/how-to-return-value-from-apex-method-to.html

Answer (score 0):

You have used String return type for your method and returning an Id.

Try this:

```
Webservice static Id fetch(Id localId)
{
        return localId;
}
```